# ACM SIG Template: unwanted ACM ISBN and DOI

Tags: acm

I'm writing a technical paper and there's a small annoyance on the pdf of my paper. At the bottom of the first page in the footnote the text

```
ACM ISBN 978-1-4503-2138-9.
DOI: 10.1145/1235
```

appears. This text throws the formatting of my paper off significantly and it leaves a huge gap of white space towards the bottom of the first page. How can I get rid of this? Is it a problem with the document class "sig-alternate-05-2015"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have any specific reason for using `sig-alternate`?

Answer (score 2):

You can add this:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@copyrightspace{\relax}
\makeatother
```

before

```
\begin{document}
```

That should solve it.

Comment: It is not clear from your answer *how* it resolves the problem due to the lack of a MWE in the question.  Perhaps you could extent your answer to provide a solution for an example illustrating the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I observe the same behaviour with the new [ACM Primary Article Template](https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template) (used as the SIG conference template), which includes the commands `\acmDOI` and `\acmISBN`. Calling these with an empty value will cause DOI / ISBN to be omitted from the ACM copyright section.

```
\acmDOI{}
\acmISBN{}
```

To remove the copyright statement as well, call `\setcopyright{none}`. (In this case, you may also want to set `\acmYear{}` to prevent printing of the conference year on a line by itself.)

To completely omit the ACM copyright and ACM reference sections, add the `nonacm` option to the `acmart` package, i.e.

```
\documentclass[sigconf,nonacm]{acmart}
```